# Python + OpenGL context indented Block

Tags: python, opengl

i am using py openGL context and my is that it tell me that a expected an indented block what character should i use with this block
    class TestContext( BaseContext ):

"""A subclass of the (dynamically determined) BaseContext, by overriding various methods, we could customize the functionality of this context, but the tutorial doesn't ask us to do this."""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docstring](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/python-docstrings) needs to be indented also. Try with this:

```
class TestContext(BaseContext):
    """A subclass of the (dynamically determined) BaseContext,
    by overriding various methods, we could customize the functionality
    of this context, but the tutorial doesn't ask us to do this.
    """
    pass
```

Comment: thank u very much for helping but plz could you tell me how did u get it done i have tried to finish it with """ but in vain

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking...What exactly is not working?

Comment: just i am writing the same thing and i finish the text with """ and press enter in the console and it tell me that an expected intend ...
i do not understand what is the problem i am using PYthon 2.7

Comment: @user3140711 if you are using the console you need to press 'Enter' one more time!

Comment: thank u very much everything is fine i did accidentally :D  thank u Herr Actress i wish i could give u rep point

Comment: i need more point tell me how and i would do it if possible when i hit ^ he say u need more point

Comment: @user3140711 ^ is for voting up and you need more reputation for that. You can accept my answer by checking the ✔ symbol under the voting buttons. It will also increase your reputation +2. Read more here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work